# Why are my forge mod exports titled incorrectly and don't show up in minecraft forge's mods tab?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I just started using Forge. I just have a very simple example mod for learning purposes. When I export the mod using `gradlew build`, everything works fine, it puts the mod into the `build\libs` folder of forge. However, the name of the file is `modid-1.0`. Now I am pretty sure I named the mod differently in my mcmod.info file. Why is it doing this and how can I change it? Furthermore, even though the mod runs correctly,(the minecraft launcher console prints the statement) but when I click on the mods tab in the mainmenu of minecraft my mod doesn't show up.

Also, another problem,  its actually generating two files into `build\libs`. One called modid-1.0 and another called modid-1.0-sources. Which one do I want to use ( meaning which one do I put into the .minecraft/mods folder)

**My mcmod.info file**

```
[
{
  "modid": "myexamplemod",
  "name": "Example Mod",
  "description": "Example placeholder mod.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "mcversion": "1.8.8",
  "url": "",
  "updateUrl": "",
  "authorList": ["ExampleDude"],
  "credits": "The Forge and FML guys, for making this example",
  "logoFile": "",
  "screenshots": [],
  "dependencies": []
}
]
```

**Mod Source Code:**

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "myexamplemod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        // some example code
        //while(true) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        System.out.println("My Mod Says: DIRT BLOCK >> "+Blocks.dirt.getUnlocalizedName());
        }
        //}
    }
    @EventHandler
    public static void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
        //while(true) {
            System.out.println("DIRT BLOCK >> "+Blocks.dirt.getUnlocalizedName());
            //}
    }
}
```

I know for testing purposes I can run it using the console command gradlew `runClient`, but I want to be able to do it the normal way for users where I can place a jar file into the mods folder of minecraft and have the mod run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the file is `modid-1.0` because you need to change it in the build.gradle file. It sits in the main directory. Open it up and about halfway down you will see a few entries

```
version = "1.0-whatever-you-want"
group= "com.mymod.examplemod" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "yourModName"
```

Change those to whatever you want, and when you build the mod it will use them to create the .jar file.

As far as the two jars being made, `modid-1.0-sources` is the de-obfuscated version of your mod. You would only use this one in development environments. Basically, if I wanted to use your mod as a dependency, I would want the -sources version. The other one `modid-1.0.jar` is the one you would want to distribute to other players

Comment: Ok great that helps a ton. Thanks, I'll accept this one. Although, the part you missed: do you have any idea why the mod wasn't showing up in the mods tab of the menu.

Comment: I think it is how you are launching it. I don't use cradle to launch a client. I have it set up in eclipse. If you ran gradlew eclipse, it should have dine this for you